# What's wrong in the code

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and these days I'm learning how to separate concerns while writing the code (MVC architecture). So I have this code where I click image of a cat and a counter variable gets incremented , each time the image is clicked. The click count is displayed with the cat image. My index.html file looks like this :

```js
 
    // Model
    var model = {
 currentCat: null,
 totalCats: [
     {
      clickCount: 0,
      name: 'Shiro',
      imgSrc: 'images/cat1.jpg',
      resetSrc: 'images/reseticon.png'
     },
     {
      clickCount: 0,
      name: 'Shadow',
      imgSrc: 'images/cat2.jpg',
      resetSrc: 'images/reseticon.png'
     },
     {
      clickCount: 0,
      name: 'Pasta',
      imgSrc: 'images/cat1.jpg',
      resetSrc: 'images/reseticon.png'
     }
 ]
    };

    //Octopus
    var octopus={
 init: function(){
  model.currentCat = model.totalCats[0];

  catListview.init();
  catView.init();
 },

 getCurrentCat: function(){
  return model.currentCat;
 },

 getCats: function(){
  return model.totalCats;
 },

 setCurrentCat: function(cat){
  model.currentCat = cat;
 },

 incrementCounter: function(){
  model.currentCat.clickCount++;
  catView.render();
 },

 resetCounter: function(){
  model.currentCat.catCount=0;
  catView.render();
 }
    };

    //View
    var catView = {
 init: function(){
  this.catEl = document.getElementById('cat');
  this.catNameEl = document.getElementById('catName');
  this.catCountEl = document.getElementById('catCount');
  this.catImageEl = document.getElementById('catImage');
  this.resetEl = document.getElementById('reset-button');

  this.catImageEl.addEventListener('click',function(){
   octopus.incrementCounter();
  });

  this.resetEl.addEventListener('click',function(){
   octopus.resetCounter();
  });

  this.render();
 },
 render: function(){
  var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
  this.catCountEl.textContent = currentCat.clickCount;
  this.catImageEl.src = currentCat.imgSrc;
  this.catNameEl.textContent = currentCat.name;
  this.resetEl.src = currentCat.resetSrc;
 }
    };

    var catListview = {
 init: function(){
  this.catListEl = document.getElementById('cat-list');
  this.render();
 },

 render: function(){
  var cats = octopus.getCats();
  this.catListEl.innerHTML = '';
  for(var i=0;i<cats.length;i++){
   thiscat = cats[i];
   var elem = document.createElement('li');
   elem.textContent = thiscat.name;
   elem.addEventListener('click',(function(thiscatCopy){
    return function(){
     octopus.setCurrentCat(thiscatCopy);
     catView.render();
    };
   })(thiscat));

   this.catListEl.appendChild(elem);
  }
 }
    };
    octopus.init();
```

```css
  img:hover{
   border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
   <title>Cat Clicker Premium</title>

 <ul id="cat-list"></ul>
 <div id="cat">
  <h2 id="catName"></h2>
  <div id="catCount"></div>
  <img id="catImage" src="" alt="image of cat">
 </div>
 <img id="reset-button" src="" alt="reset cat counter">
```

Everything works fine except the reset-counter thing. Counter doesn't reset at all. Can anyone tell me, where I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

PS: Octopus is just a fun name. It's actually the underlying controller.

Comment: can you add this to https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: and I am not seeing all the code, where is the code that is run on reset?

Comment: catCount and clickCount, what is it? Use the correct property on the object. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo in reset function

```
resetCounter: function(){
   model.currentCat.clickCount=0;
   catView.render();
 }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/UCg4SD?p=preview